# Inserting data only after verifying it does not already exists in target table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, sql-update

I am working on a script to automate the placement or "spawning" of vehicles into an online game ("DayZ"). I have a table that contains the locations and vehicle types I would like to add to the game world, however I need to make sure that a vehicle does not already exist at the location to be inserted. If it does I would just skip the insertion of the new vehicle at that location.

Originally was I was planning on gathering a recordset of all the locations and vehicles to be added and then looping through each one to determine if the location was already occupied.

```
$sql = "SELECT location, vehicle_type from vehicles_to_add";
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row)
{
  // Query the database to see if $row['location'] already exists 
  // in the vehicle_location table
  if EXISTS then
    Do not add
  else
    Add vehicle and location to the vehicle_location table
}
```

However after looking at some examples I was wondering if something could be done solely via SQL. For example ... perhaps something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_location
SELECT location, vehicle_type FROM vehicles_to_add
```

The advantage to just using SQL would be that I could create an event in the database to run on it's own. However, using this SQL ONLY method I am not sure how to check if the location already exists before adding in another vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set up a unique key on vehicle type in your table first (otherwise the duplicate key clause is useless)

```
create unique index vehicle_typekey on vehicle_location(location);
```

Then you can use a single insert statement to either insert or update

```
insert into vehicle_location select v.location, v.vehicle_type 
FROM vehicles_to_add v on duplicate key update vehicle_type=v.vehicle_type;
```

Comment: Why the index on the "vehicle_type"? Would it not be better on the vehicle_location as this is unique? "vehicle_type" will have duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry, reversed the fields in my mind, should be on location and the update should be on type, answer code updated to reflect the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in your query

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_location (a,b) SELECT v.location, v.vehicle_type FROM vehicles_to_add v
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=v.location; --you can add here to update any columns
```